# gcc/c++ - undefined reference / class error

Tags: c++, gcc

I forced to learn C++ and OpenGL development and following a few tutorial based on MFC and I tried to convert it to linux with gcc.

Most of them succeed, but this one is giving me this error when compiling.

```
/tmp/ccUmEDkj.o: In function `display()':
14new.cc:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `Titik2D::shearing(Titik2D, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is how i compile it.

```
gcc 14new.cc -lGL -lglut -lGLU -o 14
```

14new.cc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

GLsizei wh = 600 ; // initial height of window
GLsizei ww = 800 ; // initial width of window

class Titik2D {
    public: int x,y;
    Titik2D shearing(Titik2D p, int h);
};

Titik2D shearing(Titik2D p, int h)
{
    Titik2D temp;
    temp.x=p.x + h*p.y;
    temp.y=p.y;
    return temp;
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT ); //clear pixel buffer

    Titik2D hit;

    int i;
    Titik2D p[11], q[11];
    p[0].x=10; p[0].y=10;
    p[1].x=50; p[1].y=10;
    p[2].x=50; p[2].y=100;
    p[3].x=100; p[3].y=100;
    p[4].x=100; p[4].y=150;
    p[5].x=50; p[5].y=150;
    p[6].x=50; p[6].y=250;
    p[7].x=150; p[7].y=250;
    p[8].x=150; p[8].y=300;
    p[9].x=10; p[9].y=300;
    p[10].x=10; p[10].y=10;

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (i=0; i<= 10; i++)
            glVertex2i(p[i].x, p[i].y);
    glEnd();

    for (i=0; i<= 10; i++){
        q[i]= hit.shearing(p[i],2);
    }

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (i=0; i <=10; i++)
    glVertex2i(q[i].x, q[i].y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void MyInit ( void ) {
    glClearColor ( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 ); //white background
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0); // red drawing colour
    glMatrixMode ( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluOrtho2D ( 0.0, (GLdouble)ww, 0.0, (GLdouble)wh ); //Display area
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode
    ( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH );

    glutInitWindowSize(ww,wh);
    glutInitWindowPosition(180,90); //position on screen
    glutCreateWindow("opengl window");


    MyInit();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: class name is missing while defining the function.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies here: `Titik2D shearing(Titik2D p, int h) {}`

You defined a free function, NOT a member function.

Solution:

`Titik2D Titik2D::shearing(Titik2D p, int h) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the scope `Titik2D::` in the definition of shearing.
You are not defining the member function

```
Titik2D Titik2D::shearing(Titik2D p, int h)
```

You are declaring and defining a free function

```
Titik2D shearing(Titik2D p, int h)
```

Hence you get a linker error.

Answer (score 0):

And GCC is for C language. Use G++ (and cstdio) for C++.